# Implement a page-like output for python cli tool

Tags: python

I have recently started learning Python, and I wanted to write a script that acts as a command line tool that does the following:

1. It should locate a specific log file in a given directory.
2. Read the contents of the file and reformat it to a human friendly log entries
3. Output the contents to the terminal in a pager-like output.

I am able to implement 1 and 2. I use the `os` module for finding the file and I just open the file and read each line and format it.

I am currently storing the output to another file and using the "less" command from the terminal to navigate through the output file. However, what I would like to do is that the output should simply be in the console, but in a interactive pager-like output that the "less" terminal command offers.

I tried various ways to implement this, for example, the `subprocess` library. But it just prints out the entire output and exits the program.

I researched by looking into other projects such as `aws cli` which offers a similar output, but I believe the output is controlled by the API and not from the CLI tool.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html) library. It allows you to take control of the terminal, just like `less` and `vim`.

After calling the setup methods, you'll be able to write anywhere on the screen. Coupled with the user input you read, you can then move/change the displayed text to simulate scrolling.

[This GitHub project](https://github.com/mingrammer/python-curses-scroll-example/blob/master/tui.py) has a good tutorial, unfortunately much too long to summarize here.

---

You also don't need to save the output to a file to page it. You could pipe your program's output, as in:

```
python your_program.py | less
```

And I'm not sure what you've tried with `subprocess`, but calling `less` from within Python should work:

```
$ python -c "import os; os.system('less .bashrc')"
```

Comment: Telling the O.P. to use something like the curses library to reinvent the wheel seems rather silly to me. Your second suggestion makes more sense and, in fact, can be done automatically by the Python program without requiring the user to explicitly pipe the output through `less`.